# Swift3 Timer.scheduledTimer issue

Tags: swift3

```
@IBAction func attack(_ sender: UIButton) {


    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.disableAttackBtn(btnTag:sender.tag)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

func disableAttackBtn(btnTag: Int) {
    if btnTag == attack1Btn.tag {
        attack2Btn.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        attack1Btn.isEnabled = false
    }

    }
```

Trying to pass the sender.tag data to the function disableAttackBtn(btnTag:) within the Timer.scheduledTimer. But getting an error saying "Argument of #selector does not refer to an @objc method, property, or initializer"  Is there a way to pass this data to the function?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to pass a custom parameter through the timer action.

Supported is eiter no parameter

```
disableAttackBtn()
```

or **one** parameter which must be the Timer instance

```
disableAttackBtn(_ timer: Timer)
```

If you need to pass custom parameters use the `userInfo` dictionary:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(disableAttackBtn(_:)), userInfo: ["tag" : sender.tag], repeats: false)
```

---

```
fun disableAttackBtn(_ timer: Timer) {
    let info = timer.userInfo as! [String:Int]
    let tag  = info["tag"]!
    ...
```

Comment: I ended up putting doing userInfo: sender.tag to pass an Int value.  It worked!!  Thank you thank you!!